# YouTube V3 API -- Filtering related video information by duration, doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to filter out 'long' videos from the response of a YouTube V3 API request.

I have:

```
var relatedVideoInformationRequest = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    relatedToVideoId: 'oqrxjeDIWPs',
    maxResults: 10,
    //  If the relatedToVideoId parameter has been supplied, type must be video.
    type: 'video',
    videoDuration: 'medium'
});

relatedVideoInformationRequest.execute(function (relatedVideoInformationResponse) {
    console.log(relatedVideoInformationResponse);
});
```

The first result is longer than 20 minutes and the videoDuration parameter does not seem to have been applied. This happens in my code along with the YouTube API playground.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, I filed a bug internally. Feel free to [file a bug in public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) to track.

Comment: Looks like this got fixed recently. videoDuration queries now works.

Comment: @JamesZhang Doesn't seem to work for me. `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?relatedToVideoId=uuZE_IRwLNI&part=snippet&type=video&videoDuration=medium&maxResults=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` results in a video with duration over an hour.